how to remove a key from structs/maps / nested structs/maps in Elixir

Hello I have this struct
  request = %Model{
    id: 4_269_615,
    site_id: 3,
    user_id: 183_317,
    program_id: 174,
    type: %ProgramType{
      value: :CASHBACK_PROGRAM,
      __unknown_fields__: []
    },
    type_data: %ProgressProgramUser{
      id: 1_336_676,
      valid_stake: nil,
      level: nil,
      theo_ggr: nil,
      __unknown_fields__: []
    },
    start_at: ~U[2024-09-05 13:27:20.391727Z],
    end_at: nil,
    inserted_at: ~U[2024-09-05 13:27:24.152602Z],
    program_name: "test cb program 20 min GOLD NFT",
    __unknown_fields__: []
  }

i am trying to remove the __unknown_fields__: [] from struct as well as nested structs.
the code I am using is working
  def drop_unknown_fields(struct) when is_struct(struct) do
    struct
    |> Map.from_struct()
    |> drop_unknown_fields()
  end

  def drop_unknown_fields(%{} = map) when is_map(map) do
    map
    |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {key, value}, acc ->
      updated_value =
        case date?(value) do
          true -> value
          false -> drop_unknown_fields(value)
        end

      Map.put(acc, key, updated_value)
    end)
    |> Map.delete(:__unknown_fields__)
  end

  def drop_unknown_fields(value), do: value

  def date?(%DateTime{}), do: true
  def date?(%Date{}), do: true
  def date?(%NaiveDateTime{}), do: true
  def date?(_), do: false

but I think its not right approach to do it. The reason of checking date is: When I try to do nested structs, datatime is a struct as well and it get resolved into a map, which Is not required. So Can you please guide me some optimal way to clean this struct and remove :__unknown_fields__ thank you
Update: I refactored it with code below, but still looking for suggestions.
  def drop_unknown_fields(struct) when is_struct(struct) do
    struct
    |> Map.from_struct()
    |> only_consider_unknown_fields(struct)
    |> drop_unknown_fields()
  end

  def drop_unknown_fields(%{} = map) when is_map(map) do
    map
    |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {key, value}, acc ->
      updated_value =  drop_unknown_fields(value)

      Map.put(acc, key, updated_value)
    end)
    |> Map.delete(:__unknown_fields__)
  end

  def drop_unknown_fields({:consider, map}), do: drop_unknown_fields(map)

  def drop_unknown_fields({:ignore, struct}), do: struct

  def drop_unknown_fields(value), do: value

  defp only_consider_unknown_fields(map, struct) do
    case Map.has_key?(map, :__unknown_fields__) do
      true -> {:consider, map}

      false -> {:ignore, struct}
    end
  end


Do you only want to convert structs that have :__unknown_fields__ to maps? What should happen to a struct that doesn't have that key?

I have structs basicaly, so I am converting them to Map to process, I don't really want to convert Struct to Map. but the main prespective is to remove :__unknown_fields__ if it exists as key in anywhere in Parent/Nested Struct. But to answer the question yes. nothing happens to those struct which doesn't have this key they remain the same.


Here's an implementation that I think works like the way you want.

Structs which have that specific key are converted to maps, that specific key is removed, and their values are recursively processed.

Other structs are left as-is.

Non-struct maps then have their values processed and converted back into a map.

Any other value is left as-is.


  def drop_unknown_fields(%_{__unknown_fields__: _} = struct) do
    struct |> Map.from_struct() |> Map.delete(:__unknown_fields__) |> drop_unknown_fields()
  end

  def drop_unknown_fields(%_{} = struct), do: struct

  def drop_unknown_fields(%{} = map) do
    for {k, v} <- map, into: %{}, do: {k, drop_unknown_fields(v)}
  end

  def drop_unknown_fields(value), do: value

Output:
%{
  id: 4269615,
  type: %{value: :CASHBACK_PROGRAM},
  site_id: 3,
  user_id: 183317,
  program_id: 174,
  type_data: %{id: 1336676, level: nil, valid_stake: nil, theo_ggr: nil},
  start_at: ~U[2024-09-05 13:27:20.391727Z],
  end_at: nil,
  inserted_at: ~U[2024-09-05 13:27:24.152602Z],
  program_name: "test cb program 20 min GOLD NFT"
}

Full code:
defmodule Model do
  defstruct [
    :id,
    :site_id,
    :user_id,
    :program_id,
    :type,
    :type_data,
    :start_at,
    :end_at,
    :inserted_at,
    :program_name,
    :__unknown_fields__
  ]
end

defmodule ProgramType do
  defstruct [
    :value,
    :__unknown_fields__
  ]
end

defmodule ProgressProgramUser do
  defstruct [
    :id,
    :valid_stake,
    :level,
    :theo_ggr,
    :__unknown_fields__
  ]
end

defmodule Main do
  def main do
    request = %Model{
      id: 4_269_615,
      site_id: 3,
      user_id: 183_317,
      program_id: 174,
      type: %ProgramType{
        value: :CASHBACK_PROGRAM,
        __unknown_fields__: []
      },
      type_data: %ProgressProgramUser{
        id: 1_336_676,
        valid_stake: nil,
        level: nil,
        theo_ggr: nil,
        __unknown_fields__: []
      },
      start_at: ~U[2024-09-05 13:27:20.391727Z],
      end_at: nil,
      inserted_at: ~U[2024-09-05 13:27:24.152602Z],
      program_name: "test cb program 20 min GOLD NFT",
      __unknown_fields__: []
    }

    request |> drop_unknown_fields() |> IO.inspect()
  end

  def drop_unknown_fields(%_{__unknown_fields__: _} = struct) do
    struct |> Map.from_struct() |> Map.delete(:__unknown_fields__) |> drop_unknown_fields()
  end

  def drop_unknown_fields(%_{} = struct), do: struct

  def drop_unknown_fields(%{} = map) do
    for {k, v} <- map, into: %{}, do: {k, drop_unknown_fields(v)}
  end

  def drop_unknown_fields(value), do: value
end

Main.main()

